# Logging mongodb query in java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am using mongo-java-driver-2.9.1 for interacting with mongodb, I want to log the query that are fired on to the mongodb server. e.g. In java for inserting the document this is the code that I write

```java
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("mycollection");
    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("name", "MongoDB")
            .append("type", "database")
            .append("count", 1);
    coll.insert(doc);
```

for this, equivalent code in "mongo" client for inserting document in mongodb is

```java
db.mycollection.insert({
   "name" : "MongoDB",
   "type" : "database",
   "count" : 1
})
```

I want to log this second code, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Increase verbosity of mongodb server logs. It has several levels of verbosity. At some point you'll start seeing inserts or even queries in logs.

Comment: How do you set verbosity using the java driver, I searched for it but couldn't find and I want to log the query in my own logs, don't want to use server logs, I need the query so that I can even print it and show it to the user.

Comment: You set log verbosity by changing server's startup parameters. As for your custom logging, I think you have to intercept outgoing queries somewhere, right before it goes out to the database server. I don't use java driver, so can't say anything more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

I think the MongoDB Java driver has not logging support so you have to write your logging Message by your own. Here an Example:

```
DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("mycollection");
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("name", "MongoDB")
        .append("type", "database")
        .append("count", 1);
WriteResult insert = coll.insert(doc);
String msg = "";
if(insert.getError() == null){
    msg = "insert into: " + collection.toString() +" ; Object " + q.toString());
    //log the message
} else {
    msg = "ERROR by insert into: " + collection.toString() +" ; Object " + q.toString());
    msg = msg + " Error message: " + insert.getError();
}
//log the message
```